# Is there any way to "stop following" in less without pressing Ctrl+C?

Tags: linux, pipe, less

If I pipe the output of a long-running command to less, for example:

```
foreman start | less -SR
```

And I now press <kbd>F</kbd> to follow the output of foreman, is there any way to tell less to *stop* following, without pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>? Because that will also send the SIGINT to the process being piped from, in this case foreman, which will make it stop.

I just want to temporarily stop following so I can scroll and examine the output for a bit.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/905825/508092 - Looks like there's no directly supported way to leave "Forward Forever" mode, but you can fake it.

Comment: @sippybear Hmm, nice find... The accepted answer suggests the workaround I'm already using. Too bad there's no proper way to do this :(

Comment: @sippybear I [requested the feature](https://github.com/gwsw/less/issues/49#issue-570746129), but I'm not optimistic.